# Extremely Long React Script Freezing Program After Initial Render

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am working on creating a remake of Conway's Game of Life using ReactJS. So far I've only rendered a static game field with 160 cols by 120 rows for a total of 19,200 little divs.

The board seems to render passably quickly, but then for some reason the program hangs (at CodePen where I'm putting it together) for a full minute. When I looked at the Chrome Dev Tool (which I'm still very new to), it seems to show some rendering, then a full minute if scripting an full heap, and then another quick render. The color given on the key for the scripting looks the same color as Listeners.

I'm not sure what could be hanging it up since at this point everything in my react App is static and relatively simple.

Is 19,200 small divs too much for this setup? Seems unlikely. Or is this thing somehow freezing up while assigning a ton of event listeners? And how do I fix this?

Please help. I really need to understand what's happening in the background.
Bonus love to anyone who's answer helps me to solve similar issues myself next time.

```js
/**
 * @desc React Class Field renders game field
 * @param {Array} state.fieldE - even iteration game board array
 * @param {Array} state.fieldO - odd iteration game board array
 * @param {Sting} props.config - default undefined. Name sets initial field config
 * @param {Boolean} props.continue - Field continues to iterate while continue true
 * @param {Number} props.speed - sets time between iterations
 * @param {Number} props.zoom - sets board zoom in parent container
 * @param {LifeGame~Callback} props.onReset - reset field and toggle parent reset state
 * @param {LifeGame~Callback} props.incGen - reset field and toggle parent reset state
 * @returns {HTML} playable game field
 */
class Field extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.onReset = this.onReset.bind(this);

      this.state = ({
        fieldE: undefined,
        fieldO: undefined,
      });
    }

    ///Sets fieldE and fieldO in state to zero-filled arrays
    onReset() {
      const fieldE = [];
      fieldE.length = 19200;
      let i = 0;
      while (i < 19200) fieldE[i] = 0, i++;
      const fieldO = [...fieldE];

      this.setState({
        fieldE,
        fieldO
      });
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      this.onReset();
    }

    render() {
      console.log('props: ', this.props);
      console.log('state: ', this.state);

      //Converts appropriate field array to HTML for output
      const evenGen = (this.props.generation % 2 === 0);
      const fArr = evenGen ? [...this.state.fieldE] : [...this.state.fieldO];
      let len = fArr.length;
      let cols = Math.sqrt(4 / 3 * len);
      let field = fArr.map((el, i) => {
          if (i + 1 % cols === 0) {
            return <span id = 'f'
            className = 'c' > < /span>}
            return <span className = 'c' > < /span>;
          });
        let outField = [],
          i = 0,
          j = 0; outField.length = cols;

        //uses outField to separate field into rows encapsulated by divs
        while (j < len) {
          outField[i] = < div className = 'r' > {
            field.slice(j, j + cols)
          } < /div>;
          j += cols;
          i++;
        }

        return ( <
          div class = 'game-field' > {
            outField
          } <
          /div>
        );
      }

    }

    //Calls Field for render
    class LifeGame extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          config: undefined,
          isContinue: false,
          speed: 1,
          zoom: 0,
          generation: 0,
        }
      }

      render() {

        return ( <
          Field config = {
            this.state.config
          }
          isContinue = {
            this.state.continue
          }
          generation = {
            this.state.generation
          }
          speed = {
            this.state.speed
          }
          zoom = {
            this.state.zoom
          }
          />
        );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render( <
      LifeGame / > ,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
ul,
ol,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.game-field {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  row-wrap: nowrap;
}

.c {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 4px;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.4);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.4);
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.r {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 0;
  row-wrap: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 150, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  <!-- This div's content will be managed by React. -->
</div>
```

(Edit)
Additionally,
IF it turns out that 19,200 divs is too many (even though they render quickly) how are others putting together game boards with with times the elements? And how could I do the same?

It looks like something related to React doing a querySelectorAll and CalculateNewProcessedItemsBySelector after the render. These seems like hints from the Chrome DevTool, but if they are, I don't know what to make of them.

Maybe an image of the DevTool Timeline will help [image]

And the Event Log with constant calculations and query selectors without seeming to run anything that I can see.
[image]

Comment: `Is 19,200 small divs too much for this setup` - yes

Comment: I'm looking at a board right now that loads quickly with 10 times the clickable divs. There's something missing here.

Comment: When I look at the timeline, I see a half second of rasterize paint. Is it possible this has something to do with flexbox on that number of divs?

Comment: What I mean to say is that I see 4x a half second of rasterize paint.

Comment: @Adam That's the first time I've heard the term rasterize paint. I'll definitely try to look that up. Maybe that's part of it, though it seems odd since it hangs up after successfully rendering.

Comment: I take it back, it has nothing to do with flexbox, it has everything to do with the browser painting the items on screen. React renders them fast, but the browser takes forever to paint that many items. I refer back to my original comment - you've got too many divs. Find a better way to display your data. Also, I'd like to see a link to the board that has 192,000 clickable divs that all render at the same time and loads faster than yours.

Comment: @Adam The only thing that makes me hesitant bout that is that I get to see the divs appear onscreen before the freeze starts. It looks like something related to React doing a querySelectorAll and CalculateNewProcessedItemsBySelector after the render. These seems like hints from the Chrome DevTool, but if they are, I don't know what to make of them. Here's a very large game board with quick load [link](https://bitstorm.org/gameoflife/). Not sure what it's programmed in.

Comment: That's rendered on canvas, not even comparable. Maybe you should consider doing the same.

Comment: I still don't understand why this seems to render fine and then freezes for 60 seconds of querySelectorAll and CalculateNewProcessedItemsBySelector scripts after the render. Until I can get some help on that, I'll spend my time looking into this canvas and how I can put it to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that this question from a few years ago was never answered. My solution to this original question -- and the solution for most people first encountering a project where they're trying to add entirely too many html elements -- is to use a [html5 canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API).